# How to log every GET call in MVC 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I'm using Mozilla firefox browser for running my application & saw something in firebug developer tool in [Net] tab which shows how many requests have been raised to load current displayed page. Please check below images with highlighted area:**Image 1:**
[image]**Image 2:**
[image]

In Image 2, its showing the complete url for image file. I want to log all such highlighted GET calls for images, css & js files. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript can't detect that. This images and font files are probably requested by the browser because it is in a CSS file. The only way to detect that in javascript should be to parse every CSS in the page to find those URL.

But in firebug, you can filter the request by selecting a filter in the top of the Net tool. Just click on "Images" for example and you'll see only requests for images.

If you want to detect it server side. Note that some browser don't make a request at all if they want to use their cache. But if they want to request an image, you can definitively see the request server-side. It depends of your server technologies.

Comment: thanks for quick response. but the question is can we figure it out in server side? Because as I showed in image 2, if I click to this url that image gets displayed. Does it make request to server to get image? If yes then any way to catch in server side? look forward for reply.

Comment: What is your server technology ?

Comment: I mean can we get that with writing custom HttpModule or something else?